# Suitable flash uploader icm the Play! Framework

Tags: file-upload, playframework, uploadify, swfupload

I need a (flash) uploader to manage (mainly to show progress) icm the Play! framework. I have tried both SWFUpload and Uploadify, but both get stuck with an '302' error on Mac. This seems a Mac only problem (works fine on Windows), and seems to have do with Play! redirecting the page according to the route file.

So is there a solution that does work with Play!?
I guess either finding a way that there is no redirect in the request, or a implementation which does not have this problem on Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is html 5 uploader at http://www.uploadify.com which can be downloaded for $5, and it works perfect for me so far.